# The quantum correspondence principle and chaos

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiclassical

It seems to me that chaotic quantum systems should correspond to their classical counterparts, in their periodicity. For example the Hydrogen atom (gross) is a perfectly solvable, system, and such has energy eigenvalues which have rational ratios. This ensures that after a finite amount of time the quantum state will evolve to its exact starting state, just as after a period in time a planet will be in it's exact starting state. However a classical chaotic chaotic system will never return to its starting state. Does this imply that Hamiltonian's which correspond to chaotic classical systems will have irrational ratio's of their eigenvalues? Is there proof of this?

Comment: What I mean is that in the time evolution of a state the co-efficient for each state in the superposition is given by a complex constant multiplied by e^(-iEt/h). For example in Hydrogen the time varying state could be  |1>e^(-iE1t/h)+|2>e^(-iE2t/h). If E1/E2 is rational the state will eventually return to |1>+|2>.

Comment: sorry I was confused, your analogy with a planetary system made me think that you were referring to an energy eigenstate.

Comment: Those are bound systems. There's also unbound systems and systems that have a continuum of eigenstates, eg of momentum, photon frequencies etc. this sounds like another recent question about irrational units.

Comment: This is a different question. I am considering strictly chaotic bound systems.

Comment: "For example the Hydrogen atom (gross) is a perfectly solvable, system, and such has energy eigenvalues which have rational ratios. This ensures that after a finite amount of time the quantum state will evolve to its exact starting state"  This seems wrong because there's an infinite number of eigenvalues so you can easily construct a state that never comes back to its starting state.